# RegExp para darle formato a un texto JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, script

Tengo el siguiente texto de entrada:

```
Nombre                   Ciudad                 Valor

Shanar                   Ab'Dendriel           1500 gp
Memech                   Ankrahmun               20 gp
Cornelia                 Carlin                   1 gp
Hireling (Trader)        Casas y Guildhalls     120 gp
Rock In A Hard Place     Gray Beach            3000 gp
```

Como se puede apreciar, mi texto de entrada está conformado por una lista de `Nombre`, `Ciudad` y `Valor`, la cual he de formatear mediante una expresión regular para que me arroje el siguiente resultado:

```
{{!}}[[Shanar]]{{!}}{{!}}[[Ab'Dendriel]]{{!}}{{!}}1500 [[gp]]
{{!}}-
{{!}}[[Memech]]{{!}}{{!}}[[Ankrahmun]]{{!}}{{!}}20 [[gp]]
{{!}}-
{{!}}[[Cornelia]]{{!}}{{!}}[[Carlin]]{{!}}{{!}}1 [[gp]]
{{!}}-
{{!}}[[Hireling (Trader)]]{{!}}{{!}}[[Casas y Guildhalls]]{{!}}{{!}}120 [[gp]]
{{!}}-
{{!}}[[Rock In A Hard Place]]{{!}}{{!}}[[Gray Beach]]{{!}}{{!}}3000 [[gp]]
```

Para eso necesito varios reemplazos que hagan lo siguiente por cada línea:

1. Encerrar entre `[[]]` cada `nombre`, `ciudad` y `gp`
2. Agregar `{{!}}` al principio de cada `nombre`
3. Reemplazar el espacio entre `nombre` y `ciudad` con `{{!}}{{!}}`
4. Reemplazar el espacio entre `ciudad` y `valor` con `{{!}}{{!}}`
5. Separar cada línea `nombre`, `ciudad`, `valor` con `{{!}}-`

Dando como resultado:

```
{{!}}[[nombre]]{{!}}{{!}}[[ciudad]]{{!}}{{!}}valor [[gp]]
{{!}}-
{{!}}[[nombre]]{{!}}{{!}}[[ciudad]]{{!}}{{!}}valor [[gp]]
{{!}}-
...
```

### Consideraciones:

Requiero que esta expresión regular sea lo más básica posible, evitando, si se puede, el uso de `arrays` o funciones muy complicadas, ya que realmente no requiero almacenar ningún dato, ni pelear con wikitexto y `JavaScript`, tan sólo es para darle formato al texto que mostré anteriormente de la forma más básica posible. Todo esto deberé traducirlo a código wiki y preferiblemente quisiera evitar en lo posible el uso de `JavaScript` avanzado. No importa si el código es muy extenso.

Yo he intentado hacer una expresión regular basándome únicamente en reemplazos de espacios en blanco por `{{!}}`, pero no me ha salido del todo bien y he terminado mandando a la papelera todo mi esfuerzo.

Esta expresión regular será usada en una plantilla, a la cual por medio de un parámetro he de insertar los datos para mostrar como resultado el mismo texto pero con el formato solicitado. Básicamente mi intención es copiar el texto, pegarlo, procesarlo, y obtener el texto con el formato, todo en la misma página.

Ese formato corresponde a las celdas de una tabla construida en Mediawiki. Tengo un parámetro que tomará el texto sin formato, después de guardar la página el texto será formateado y el resultado en pantalla será una tabla.

### Nota:

Si has trabajado con wikitexto y tienes ciertas nociones, puedo mostrar exactamente lo que llevo hecho en mi plantilla wiki con wikitexto puro, de ese modo podrás tener una idea muchísimo más amplia de lo que busco.

Comment: ¿Puedes asegurar que la separación entre cada columna es de al menos dos espacios? Si no es así sería muy difícil resolver tu problema a no ser que haya un máximo de caracteres por columna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te preguntaba en los comentarios, si puedes asegurar que hay al menos dos espacios entre los datos cada columna y que las mismas no contienen nunca más de un espacio seguido, entonces podrías detectar la separación de las columnas haciendo coincidir dos o más espacios (`{2,}`):

Expresión regular:

```
/^(.+?) {2,}(.+?) {2,}(\d+) (gp)$/gm
```

- `^` Principio de cada línea
- `(.+?)` Cualquier carácter una o más veces de manera perezosa
- `{2,}` Dos o más espacios
- `(\d+)` Uno o más dígitos
- `gp` Carácter `g` seguido del carácter `p`
- `$` Final de cada línea
- `gm` *flag* `g` (global) y *flag* `m` para multilínea (`^` y `$` reconocerán el principio y final de cada línea)

```js
const entrada = `
Shanar                   Ab'Dendriel           1500 gp
Memech                   Ankrahmun               20 gp
Cornelia                 Carlin                   1 gp
Hireling (Trader)        Casas y Guildhalls     120 gp
Rock In A Hard Place     Gray Beach            3000 gp
`;

const reg = /^(.+?) {2,}(.+?) {2,}(\d+) (gp)$/gm;

const salida = entrada.replace(reg, '{{!}}[[$1]]{{!}}{{!}}[[$2]]{{!}}{{!}}$3 [[$4]]\n{{!}}-');

console.log(salida);
```

**Edición:**

Si te hiciera falta de manera obligatoria que cada línea esté separada por `{{!}}-` y que no se añadiera esta cadena de caracteres al final, podrías crear un array usando [RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Regexp/exec) y al final unirlo usando dicha cadena (que según explicas añade complejidad a la solución que buscas y deseas evitarlo):

```js
const entrada = `
Shanar                   Ab'Dendriel           1500 gp
Memech                   Ankrahmun               20 gp
Cornelia                 Carlin                   1 gp
Hireling (Trader)        Casas y Guildhalls     120 gp
Rock In A Hard Place     Gray Beach            3000 gp
`;

const reg = /^(.+?) {2,}(.+?) {2,}(\d+) (gp)$/mg;

const array = [];

while ((arr = reg.exec(entrada)) !== null) {
  array.push(arr);
}

const salida = array.map(i => `{{!}}[[${i[1]}]]{{!}}{{!}}[[${i[2]}]]{{!}}{{!}}${i[3]} [[${i[4]}]]`).join('\n{{!}}-\n');

console.log(salida);
```

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu valiosa colaboración. Acabo de probar el primer código que me enviaste y está casi casi perfecto, solo un pequeño detalle al principio:


A las {{!}} antes del nombre le falta una }}


{{!}[[Shanar]]{{!}}{{!}}... le falta un "}"
{{!}}-
{{!}[[Memech]]{{!}}{{!}}...


Si puedes hacer que sea de la forma {{!}} en vez de {{!} daría con todo a la perfección. Tan solo falta una "}"

El segundo código funciona perfecto, pero me quedaré con el primero, ya que es mucho más fácil de traducir a wikitexto.

Estaré pendiente para subir el resultado.

Comment: Tienes razón @NickCam, me había faltado, añadido ;)